# How to convert a select statement in mysql into a query in java?

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

I have a select statement inside MySQL.

```
select * from tbl_user where path like '%,id,%'
```

How can I convert it to a query in Java? What I want to pass `id`.

Comment: Well ok, but what DAO library are you using ?

Comment: You might want to reread [ask] and improve on the quality of your question, e.g. by showing what you've tried so far. Do you already know about JDBC, how to create a connection, how to create a statement and most importantly `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: You need to learn JDBC. That will do exactly what you need here.

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't work .     @Query(value = "select u.id,u.role_id,u.user_name,u.path as 'Child Users' from tbl_user u where u.path like ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<Tbl_user> findAllChildUsers(int id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe

```
@Query(value = "select * from tbl_user where path like CONCAT('%,',?1,',%')", nativeQuery = true) 
Iterable<Tbl_user> findAllChildUsers(int id);
```

will help

Comment: I tried this way and it didn't work

Comment: @bin  I update my answer, and maybe you should paste you code here

Comment: thanks, based on your answer i changed it to.

Comment: ``@Query(value = "select * from tbl_user where path like CONCAT('%,',?1,',%')", nativeQuery = true)
  Iterable<Tbl_user> findAllChildUsers(int id);``

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what framework/library are you using.
in hibernate you can use :id, but you have to also check that it is native query.

In some libraries you just pass a String as a query.

Comment: i'm using springframework's jdbc library